# How to add a server-side Component into a server-side Component with Vaadin 7?

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have two widget having the same structures like here :

[image]

Lets say : MyComponent1.java and MyComponent2.java .

On Server Side i want to do following :

```
public class MyComponent1 extends AbstractComponentContainer {

       //Some Fields and RPC initialisation
       .....

       public MyComponent1(){
          registerRpc(rpc);
          MyComponent2 comp2 = new MyComponent2();
          listOfComponents.add(comp2);
          super.addComponent(comp2); //
       }

       ....

       @Override
       public Iterator<Component> iterator() {

       ComponentIterator<Component> compIterator = null;
        try {
         compIterator = new ComponentIterator<Component>(listOfComponents.iterator());

         return componentIterator;
        } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         return null;
        }
       }
}
```

Despite all my research i cannot find why compiler crash and shout this Error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector$CombinedIterator.hasNext(AbstractClientConnector.java:494)

Is there another way to add a server-side component into another server-side component?